In "Fallout" lore, how does removing a fusion core actually affect an occupied power armor?
In the 2024 Fallout TV series (Season 1, Episode 5: "The Past"), there’s this scene where Thaddeus, with a bit of maneuvering, manages to remove the fusion core right out of Maximus’ T-60 power armor. And just like that, Maximus finds himself imprisoned within his power armor—a vulnerability reminiscent of another flaw I’ve noted concerning the use of a knife.
This got me thinking about my Fallout 4 days. In Fallout 4, you could pickpocket and steal fusion cores from unsuspecting NPCs. But unlike in the TV series, they weren’t left imprisoned in their power armor; instead, the power armor will (automatically?) open, allowing them to exit.



I’ve considered that this might simply be a gameplay mechanic to avoid leaving a trail of NPCs stuck in power armor.
But from a lore perspective, it raises the question: would they actually be stuck? Has there been any mention in previous Fallout games or related media about the repercussions of taking a fusion core from a power armor with someone inside, prior to this depiction in the TV series?

There are different representation of fusion cores between fallout4 and 76 as well as survival and none survival mode. They also act differently for the player character as well as for npcs
